# Phonegap twitter plugin for Android

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins

I want to integrate twitter having compose tweet feature in my application using Phonegap.I am following https://github.com/ObjetDirect/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/Twitter/www. Now   in readme file they have given the instructions, for compose tweet how can I modify my index.html page? Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it using the concept of childbrowser. I have done this. Use the link: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this example of how to retrieve messages, photos, names... from twitter using javascript.
I've made it and with the help of CSS was fantastic!

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/42450600/PhoneGap%20Ajax%20Sample

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want compose tweet feature in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I think my tutorial describes what you want to do. See [TMT5P1](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt5p1).

Requires Child Browser [plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser) (no Twitter plugin needed) to do OAuth 1.0a Twitter login. Video [demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84jmuXS8GJI) on PhoneGap / Android plugins.

In TMT5P1 user logs in to their twitter account from your phonegap app, gives permission to the app to access their twitter account, after which all Twitter APIs are available via javascript in your app. Includes composing and sending a tweet.